# Export and Importing data without a physical XML file between two websites

Tags: xml

OK I have this situation,

Assuming there are two mirror sites, for example:

```
masterwebsite.com

slavewebsite.com
```

masterwebsite.com is where the administrators edit content for a certain plugin.
slavewebsite.com is where users will be using the plugin but they cannot edit any of the content or plugin functionality.

Is it possible to export a certain XML variable as a string (as an output of an export function) then to be read by a calling function in a slave website without ever creating a XML physical file?

UPDATE: The XML file variable is outputted by:

```
$myxmlvariable = $xml->array2xml($doc_data, 'documentation_export');
```

This is found in the export function let say:

```
doc_export()
```

It will be located in the masterwebsite.com

And the function to import will be:

```
doc_import($xml)
```

This will be found in the slavewebsite.com.

Take note that these are Wordpress plugin implementations.

If yes, what are the concepts and necessary steps? I'm not exactly looking for code, just the principles of operation. If someone can shed some light on this, I would highly appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: In what sense is your XML variable an XML variable when there is no XML file involved? Or do you just want to avoid having to create a new XML file from an existing XML file? If so, why?

Comment: Thanks Class Stacker for the update. I have edited my question. Actually the XML variable is generated from an array using array2xml class.

Comment: And by "creating a physical XML file", you mean, storing it? Or do you mean, using XML as a format at all? Also, what will be the amount of data you intend to transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no physical xml file ? i think you want to work with this xml on the flay or as background process . i think a simple REST service can help you to do so . and you may consume this rest service using simple AJAX call where the output is expected .
if you choose REST then [this](http://blog.garethj.com/2009/02/17/building-a-restful-web-application-with-php/) link may help you